# How to check if a key with an specific value in a dictionary exist on Python? Dictionary with arrays as values

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, dictionary, if-statement, notin

I have the following dictionary called `the_dictionary_list`:

```
the_dictionary_list= {'Color': ['Amarillo.png', 'Blanco.png',
'Rojirosado.png', 'Turquesa.png', 'Verde_oscuro.png', 'Zapote.png'],
'Cuerpo': ['Cuerpo_cangrejo.png'], 'Fondo': ['Oceano.png'], 'Ojos':
['Antenas.png', 'Pico.png', 'Verticales.png'], 'Pinzas':
['Pinzitas.png', 'Pinzotas.png', 'Pinzota_pinzita.png'], 'Puas':
['Arena.png', 'Marron.png', 'Purpura.png', 'Verde.png']}
```

I wanted to check if it has a particular key with a particular value (in its array), so I typed the following code:

```
if ('Color', 'None') in the_dictionary_list.items():
    print('This is True')
else:
    print('This is False')
    
if ('Color', 'Amarillo.png') in the_dictionary_list.items():
    print('This is True')
else:
    print('This is False')
```

The output was the following:

> This is False
>
> This is False

Which is 50% false, because the second `if statement` should print `This is True`, I tried to look for answers in other sites but it seems that dictionaries with arrays within are very uncommon, but legal in the end, how else can I evaluate if a particular pair of key-value actually exists in the dictionary above?

Comment: Why not try something like: `'Amarillo.png' in the_dictionary_list['Color']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, simply by using a function:

```
the_dictionary_list= {
    'Color': ['Amarillo.png', 'Blanco.png', 'Rojirosado.png', 'Turquesa.png', 'Verde_oscuro.png', 'Zapote.png'],
    'Cuerpo': ['Cuerpo_cangrejo.png'],
    'Fondo': ['Oceano.png'],
    'Ojos': ['Antenas.png', 'Pico.png', 'Verticales.png'],
    'Pinzas': ['Pinzitas.png', 'Pinzotas.png', 'Pinzota_pinzita.png'],
    'Puas': ['Arena.png', 'Marron.png', 'Purpura.png', 'Verde.png']}

def existe(llave, valor, dicc):
    return llave in dicc and valor in dicc[llave]

print(existe('Color', 'None', the_dictionary_list))
print(existe('Color', 'Amarillo.png', the_dictionary_list))
```

Output:

> False
>
> True